# React state is updated separately by the setState .methods

Tags: reactjs

I've been scratching my head to get around this issue for hours and I can't seem to find a proper solution for my problem.- I'm sure it's a common problem, I'm still trying to get stronger in React.

I do have a shopping cart that I'm trying to create. I'm calling the list of items from a hard-coded JSON file. My problem is I'm trying to hold two different values in my state, one is for quantities of the items which I add it every time quantity of the item changes in the shopping cart and at my store cart I only want to store the id of the number and the quantities;

So, for example, if a user choose '3' quantities on item1 and '2' quantities on item2, my state should be  {id:quantitiy}-> {1:3,2:2} but instead, it overrides the older state and updates it
such as it stores 1:3 first, and then 2:2 overwrites it.

Is there a way I can handle this? I also tried using an array and pushing the item with spread operator but then it made me realize that I do have two different states for some reason and each of them is holding their state and not updating the cart together.

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "description": "TV",
      "unit_price": 2,
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "description": "Computer",
      "unit_price": 12,
    }
  ]
```

}

And I do have a component to handle adding a new item to the cart

```
class Item extends Component {
  state = {
    quantity: 1,
    cart: {}
  };

  handleInput = event => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state.quantity,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  addToCart = id => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      cart: {
        [id]: this.state.quantity
      }
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { item } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Item: {item.description}</h3>
        <p>Price: {item.price}</p>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => this.addToCart(item.id)}>Add To Cart</button>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="quantity"
            value={this.state.quantity}
            onChange={this.handleInput}
          />
        </div>
        <Link to={{ pathname: "/cart", state: { cart: this.state.cart } }}>
          View Cart
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Item;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to spread the previous cart state into the new state:

```js
addToCart = id => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    cart: {
      ...(prevState.cart || {}), // keep previous cart state
      [id]: this.state.quantity
    }
  }));
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, this is still over-riding the state. I want it to keep, 1:1, 2:2, but it overrides 1:1 with 2:2, or  I think it might be because of the way I designed my input forms, I do have one handle for multiple input forms. @ray hatfield